# GLFW Monitor Callback not Triggered

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, glfw

I am working on a set of GLFW 3.1.2 bindings for Node.js. I've run into an issue with one particular API, the `glfwSetMonitorCallback` API specifically.

The issue is that it's not being triggered when I disconnect or connect a monitor to my system.

The following is my callback handler:

```
void monitor::onGLFWMonitor (GLFWmonitor* monitor, int action) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    auto it = monitor::monitorObjects.find(monitor);
    Local<Object> jsMonitor;

    if (it == monitor::monitorObjects.end()) {
        // New monitor, add it
        jsMonitor = monitor::monitorObjectTemplate.Get(isolate)->NewInstance();
        jsMonitor->SetAlignedPointerInInternalField(0, monitor);
        jsMonitor->SetInternalField(1, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "GLFWmonitor"));
        CopyablePersistent<Object> perst(isolate, jsMonitor);
        MonitorIndexedPair<Object> pr(monitor, perst);
        it = monitor::monitorObjects.insert(pr).first;
    } else {
        jsMonitor = it->second.Get(isolate);
    }

    if (action == GLFW_DISCONNECTED) {
        // Monitor removed, clean up!
        jsMonitor->SetAlignedPointerInInternalField(0, NULL);
        monitor::monitorObjects.erase(it);
        // TODO Cleanup video modes once implemented
    }

    if (monitor::monitorCallback.IsEmpty()) {
        // No callback, do nothing
        return;
    }

    Local<Function> callback = monitor::monitorCallback.Get(isolate);
    const unsigned int argc = 2;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = {
        jsMonitor,
        Number::New(isolate, action)
    };
    callback->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
}
```

It is set as part of any call to `glfwInit` like so:

```
void core::init (const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    bool result = glfwInit();

    if (result == GL_TRUE) {
        // Setup callbacks
        glfwSetMonitorCallback(monitor::onGLFWMonitor);
    }

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(Boolean::New(isolate, result == GL_TRUE));
}
```

I have added several `printf` statements into the callback function and none of them are ever produced. Additionally, if I call `glfwGetMonitors`, it always returns the wrong number of monitors. EG: I have two monitors, disconnect one, and `glfwGetMonitors` still returns two monitors.

I'm seeing this issue on multiple computers running Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1, and Windows 10. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging around, I've determined the cause of my issues. The simple test case I wrote never called `glfwPollEvents`, so naturally none of my callbacks would ever be triggered.